# Protege Merging Individuals

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, protege

I have created an ontology. There is a temperature sensor class and humidity sensor class. the can have sensor values.

Now I want to define a class where if the temperature sensor has value less than 25 and humidity sensor has value less than 20 then it will define a normal state. I m not sure should I define a class or something else. In the result I want that when a temperature sensor's and a humidity sensor's value is less than defined rule I can call them as a member of normal state. but any of the sensor violate the rule neither sensor will be the member of that class

Answer (score 0):

```
PREFIX rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
```

PREFIX rdfs:    http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#
PREFIX temp: http://www.sensor.com/Temper#
select *
{
?a temp:value ?c
}
if(value>25 "NORMAL", "NON-NORMAL")